# Open Graph working for Google+ and LinkedIn but not Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Firstly, I am not a full time programmer so go easy ;-) I've also read through a number of answers on here but none have yet fixed my problem, hence asking this.

I have added Open Graph code to amy website and the Title, Description and Image specified are all working when sharing a link on LinkedIn and Google+ but do not work on Facebook.

The Facebook debugger gives me a "Could not retrieve data from URL" Message. 
If I test with http://www.opengraph.in it shows me what I'd expect to see.

A sample URL which exhibits this problem is http://www.newsbase.com/newsbasearchive/cotw.jsp?pub=energo&issue=608

Thanks,

Al.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the Facebook debugger for your URI and got the same basic result:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newsbase.com%2Fnewsbasearchive%2Fcotw.jsp%3Fpub%3Denergo%26issue%3D608
--- Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Running the W3C validator on it shows a number of issues that might be confusing to an accurate HTML parser, but allow poor, ad-hoc parsers to muddle through.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newsbase.com%2Fnewsbasearchive%2Fcotw.jsp%3Fpub%3Denergo%26issue%3D608&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3
--- 142 Errors, 21 warning(s)

However, copying it to one my own servers shows that it works just fine there with the same exact content, instead grumbling that:

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

So it's pretty clearly not an issue with the normal output for your webpage.  I checked with this just in case Facebook's agent was changing behavior:

wget -np -nd -nH -U "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" -O foo.html 'http://www.newsbase.com/newsbasearchive/cotw.jsp?pub=energo&issue=608'

But the result was bytewise identical.

Note that the facebook debugger is fine with http://www.newsbase.com/newsbasearchive itself.  But once the "cotw.jsp" is added, it's game over.

My guess is that the cotw.jsp itself is doing something undesirable.